# make <li> as whole <a> (link) vertical menu

Tags: html, css

any idea to make LI as whole link?

```
#nav{
position: relative;
width: 120px;
}
#nav a {
display: inline;
width: 100%
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul li{
background: #c0c0c0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #404040;
}
#nav ul ul{
position: absolute;
left: 81px;
display: none;
}
#nav ul ul li{
background: #c0c0c0;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
display: inline;
}
```

here's the link:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/wX2ss/)

options I tried:

> 1. a {display: block; }  -->this worked, but the second UL drops down.
> 2. a {display: inline-block;}  -->second UL issue is fixed but LI is not a link.
> 3. a {display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%; } --> same as 2.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the padding that it doesn't work. The element is actually overlapping the others.

```
#nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 80px;
    display: none;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

You can find the full demo here:
[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wX2ss/27/)

Comment: Xeano! you are one of the reason why internet is so awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: hehe, that's very nice of you. If you like the answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}

#nav ul li{
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #404040;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wX2ss/16/

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this css

```
    #nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

you can check here

http://jsfiddle.net/wX2ss/30/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#nav{
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}
#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul li{
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #404040;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 43px;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
}
#nav ul ul li{
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: inline;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ThHrA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
            #navbar ul li {
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            }

            #navbar ul li ul  {
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            }

            #navbar ul li:hover>ul {
            visibility: visible;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            }

            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="link">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="link">x</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link">y</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link">z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```